# In F#, who pumps the message queue?

Tags: f#

In F# if I do something like
let form = new Form(Text = "MyForm")
and run it in FSI, the form will display and update normally, and even recieve messages. However, who is pumping the message queue? There is no Application.Run call here. I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As ildjarn says, F# Interactive implements its own message loop. Interestingly, the message loop is not hardcoded in F# Interactive, so you can change it. This is quite useful, because the default one is based on Windows Forms, but there are other GUI frameworks you may want to use.

To do that, you would need to implement `IEventLoop` interface and then assign your instance to the `fsi.EventLoop` property. For more information see:

- [The source code for `IEventLoop` interface](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/fsiaux.fsi)
- [The default implementation that uses WinForms](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/fsiaux.fs)
- [A simple implementation that I wrote for Gtk#](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3dbd89b23e34#fsharp/bonus/load-gtk.fsx)

Comment: Thanks so much for the links! Great info.

Answer (score 4):

FSI has its own message pump for this very reason.